# Surface integral over the surface of a cylinder.

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals

I want to calculate the surface integral of $A=(4x,-2y^2,z^2)$ over the convex surface $S$ of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=4$ between $z=0$ and $z=3$. I get the unit normal vector $n$ as $(x/2,y/2,0)$. Now $A\cdot n=2x^2-y^3$.
I project the convex surface on the $xz$ plane and proceed to find $|n\cdot j|$ which comes out to be $y/2$. From the equation of the cylinder $y^2=4-x^2$ which leads to $y=\sqrt{4-x^2}$. Now
$$
\int_{S} A\cdot n dS= \iint (2x^2-y^3)/|n\cdot j| dxdz
 = 2\iint((2x^2/y)- y^2) dxdz \\ = 2\iint ((2x^2/\sqrt{4-x^2})- 4+x^2) dxdz
$$
where the limits of integration are from $-2$ to $2$ in case of $x$ and $0$ to $3$ in case of $z$. When I evaluate this double integral in Wolframalpha, I get $24π-64$ as the answer. But my book evaluates it as $48π$. I am not able to understand where have I committed mistake. Please suggest.

Comment: Any reason you're not doing this in cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: My book has it done in cylindrical coordinates. And as a side note to the answer it says that it could have been evaluated by projecting the surface on either $xz$ or $yz$ planes. So I am trying just that.

Comment: If you're going to do it in cartesian coordinates, I would recommend projecting on the $yz$-plane so that you can take advantage of the symmetry (note the $y^3$ in the integrand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only integrated over the half of the cylinder where $y>0$. You need to also include the integral for the half where $y < 0$. Then $y = -\sqrt{4-x^2}$, $|n\cdot j| = -y/2$, and the integral will come out to $24\pi + 64$. Add those together and you get $48\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate in cylindrical coordinates with $r=2$,

$$\int_0^3 dz\int_0^{2\pi} (2r^2\cos^2 t -r^3\sin^3t )r dt
=48\pi$$